# Prove that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ can't be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Assume there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $k^2=n(n+1)(n+2)$. Now I probably need to show some contradiction. I noticed that $\gcd(n,n+1)=\gcd(n+1,n+2)=1$ which could maybe help.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey :) And $\operatorname{gcd}(n, n+2) \in\{1,2\}$. If $n$ is odd, then all three factors are pairwise prime, which means that all of them have to be squares.

Answer (score 0):

Let's note that n, n+1 and n+2 are 3 consecutif integers, so we do know that (n,n+1) = 1. Also, (n+1,n+2) = 1. Now, if n is even, n+2 is even, and (n,n+2) = 2 ((n,n+2) cannot be larger than 2 because consecutif multiples of any integer k must be spaced of k numbers). So, n(n+1)(n+2) = 4 k, where k is the products of the different divisors of n, n+1 and n+2. Now, let's notice that, for any integer m, (m+1)^2 -m^2 = 2m + 1, meaning that 2 perfect squares are at least space of 2m + 1 integers (i mean of an odd numbers of numbers). So, if either n, n+1 or n+2 is a perfect square, the others cannot be perfect square. Now, let's write n =  2ab...c, n+1 = de...f, n+2 = 2gh...i. It follows that k = abcdefgh...i. But, since (n+1,n+2) = 1, and (n/2,n+2/2)= 2 and (n,n+1) = 1, the integers abc...i are all relatively prime to each others, and since one of them is not a perfect square, their product (k) is not a perfect square, so 4k is not a perfect square.
Now, if n is odd, then n+1 is even, but then n(n+1)(n+2) = 2qsdf...b, where qsdf...b is an odd number, so 2qsdf...b cannot be a perfect square.